# PHP contact form (sendmail) not receiving emails

Tags: javascript, php

Below is the code for a contact form that I'm using at my site.

I cannot seem to make it work (not getting emails), and I would love to make it redirect to homepage after successful send. Thankful for any help!

```
<?php
// Variables
/*
*SendMail: by fb.com/nurealamsabbir
*/
$name = trim($_POST['name']);
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$message = trim($_POST['message']);
$select_industry = trim($_POST['select_industry']);
// $subject= trim($_POST['subject']);
$subject = 'Message From caracraft';
if(!$subject) {
    $subject = 'Message From caracraft';
}
$to = "example@gmail.com"; // Change with your email address
//echo "{$to}";
if( isset($name) && isset($email) ) {

    // Avoid Email Injection and Mail Form Script Hijacking
    $pattern = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:|to:)/i";
    if( preg_match($pattern, $name) || preg_match($pattern, $email) || preg_match($pattern, $message) ) {
        exit;
    }
    // Email will be send

//Must end on first column

    $headers = "From: $name <$email>\r\n";
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    // PHP email sender
    mail($to, $sub, $body, $headers);

    // PHP email sender
  if(mail( "getthemesopera@gmail.com", $_POST['subject'], $_POST['message'], $headers )){
    echo "Thank you, I have received your message.";
  }
  else {
    echo "Email cannot be sent now. Please try later.";
  }
  //  Replace with your email 
  return false;
}

?>
```

Comment: You can't be sure a mail has been sent at this point, you can only know whether the server accepted it.

Comment: How do I make sure that email is sent?

Comment: Usually people include a one pixel remote image in the body and when the client requests that image you know the email has been opened (unless, that is, they block images). But there's no way of knowing if a mail has been received, short of asking the receiver.

Comment: Check your mail_log. Also, try sending to a different email address. Gmail may be marking it as spam.